# Is this verse really there in Shatapatha Brahmana? Please show me the reference

Tags: shatapatha-brahmana, purusha

This verse **"Tasya prajapatirardhameva martyamasidardhamrutam"** is usually supposed to be part of the Shatapatha Brahmana, and according to certain users, meant that the Purusha would be half man and half divine. However, I have not found any mention of this passage in any of the versions of the brahmana quoted (sorry, I have no satisfactory knowledge of Sanskrit, which makes my research difficult) If you guys find it I would be  grateful ;)

Comment: I can only find church-related non-sourced pages when searching for the text. I can't find anything in the sanskrit text itself either. Do you have the same text with diacritics or in Devanagari?

Comment: @Gabe Hiemstra unfortunately not, I believe that it is something made up, since it's found only in pseudo christian circles on the internet

Comment: Why one must believe what a Church is circulating? Churches in India have been known for their evangelization and proselytization attempts in the Hindu neighborhood via these practices only. Annals of History have enough proof for these kinds of "made-up" lies being spread by the Non-Indian Religions to convert people.